# How to configure appsettings on a auto-generated preview environment

Tags: azure, appsettings, azure-static-web-app

How can I change the appsettings on the preview environemnts that are generated by the Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD Github Action for each pull request?

I can go to the portal, navigate to the generated environment and change its appsettings. Doing this manually for each new pull request is error prone and will become tedious really fast.

I couldn't find any reference to this in the [Build Configuration For Azure Static Webapps docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions) so I'm assuming it can't be configured that way.
I also couldn't find any reference to SWA environments in the [CLI docs](https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/).
I looked into [deployment environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/deployment-environments/how-to-configure-use-cl) but it looks like this is some other kind of deployment environment as it keeps mentioning devcenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Azure Portal`, While Creating Static Web App, after providing the `GitHub Repo` and `Branch` details, we will get an option to preview the Workflow file.

[image]

> I can go to the portal, navigate to the generated environment and change its appsettings

Yes, In Configuration Section we have an option to add the `App settings`. But it is a manual work, which is not advised to follow.

[image]

Once we click on  `Review + create` and create the Static Web App, a new folder with name `.github/workflows` will be created in the `GitHub Repository`.

[image]

It contains the same workflow file (`preview file`), which we saw while creating the `Static WebApp` in Azure Portal.

- We can edit the Workflow manually.
- To update the `appsettings/configurations` in the workflow, we can specify the steps in the existing `workflow` file.
- We can use either `Powershell/Azure CLI` commands to update the `Appsettings`.

```cs
az staticwebapp appsettings set --name YourStaticWebAppname --setting-names "message=HelloEveryOne"
```

***Sample code for Updating App settings: ***
Before `Build and deploy`step  in Workflow, add the below steps.

```cs
- name: Build And Deploy
- run : Your Update appsettings Script
```

To edit the Workflow file, click on the `.github/workflow` => `.yml` file

[image]

References taken from MSDoc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings).

### Update

As per the discussion in GitHub, adding appsettings to the preview environment is not currently supported in the default `Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD`.

Comment: This answer would be more usefull if you removed everything up to the part that about editing the workflow and instead add the missing part on how to configure a static web app's appsetings for a specific environment from the CLI.
For clarity's sake I'll append what I tried with the CLI already.

Comment: We can set `environment variables` in GitHub and use them in the workflow to update the appsettings.

Comment: Please check this GitHub link [1](https://github.com/JabRef/JabRefOnline/issues/1335) and [2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22552) once.

Comment: Thanks. If you post an answer just stating that this is not currently supported in the default Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD step and adding it to a new step is also not possible because the azure CLI doesnt support it yet until that issue is resolved I can mark it as an answer :)

Comment: @BorisCallens - Please check the update section in the answer.

Comment: I'll give you the Answer mark, but please empathize with any future reader of this question and think about how they would want to see the answer to this question. I can't imagine they are looking for a carbon copy of the documentation and are looking for the essential piece of the answer at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Setting appsettings on a specific environment is not currently supported in the Azure Static Web apps CI/CD nor by the Azure CLI.
There is a [discussion in GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22552) about it.

Comment: I extracted the sentence that answers the question from [here][4] and the comment thread as it is otherwise easily missed and added some essential words to make it complete. To remain fair, I will make it wiki and keep the answer mark on the original.

  [4]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75273821/11333